# Inserting borders for table rows and columns in a tablelayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I've currently designed table using table layout in android which contains some data. I need to insert borders for the table's rows & columns. I somehow managed to give background for each row. But my outcome is not what I expected. I don't know how can I acquire the horizontal line between the columns. Also let me know where I went wrong. In this post I have attached 2 images one being the expected output & the another one is the output which I got now.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp">

    <TableRow
        android:background="#ca0a29"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Size"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Height"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chest"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Waist"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Neck"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arm"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="India"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XL"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20-21"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22-23"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24-25"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25-26"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"

            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="India"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XL"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20-21"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22-23"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24-25"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25-26"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="India"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XL"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20-21"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22-23"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24-25"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25-26"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="India"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XL"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20-21"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22-23"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24-25"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25-26"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="India"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XL"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20-21"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22-23"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24-25"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25-26"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/table_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="India"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XL"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20-21"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22-23"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24-25"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="25-26"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"

            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

1 Actual Output

[image]

2 Expected Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is too simple just remove background from all Table row
like below codde.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

<TableRow
    android:background="#ca0a29"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Country"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Size"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Height"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chest"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Waist"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Neck"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arm"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="India"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XL"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20-21"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22-23"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="24-25"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25-26"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"

        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow

    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="India"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XL"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20-21"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22-23"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="24-25"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25-26"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow

    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="India"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XL"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20-21"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22-23"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="24-25"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25-26"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow

    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="India"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XL"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20-21"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22-23"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="24-25"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25-26"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow

    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="India"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XL"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20-21"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22-23"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="24-25"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25-26"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow

    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="India"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XL"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20-21"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22-23"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="24-25"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25-26"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"

        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</TableRow>
```

just paste this code and run this. It is same as your accepted output